# Can I hide a div by default until JavaScript calls to fade it in?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div on my page and using JavaScript to hide it until the user clicks in a text field. That will fade-in the div. The problem I'm having is while the page is loading the div quickly flashes up on the page and then hides. Is there a way that I can set my div to hide by default and then only once the user clicks on the text area then the div appears? 
At the moment it flashes up for a brief second while the page loads then hides.

Iv'e tried putting the CSS style to `display:none;` but this means then the div doesn't fade in at all.

```
<script>
$(".search_prompt").hide();
$(function() {
    $(".search_prompt").hide();
    var focusin_flag = false,
    focusout_flag = false;
    $("#text").focusin(function() {
        if (!focusin_flag) {
            $(".search_prompt").show();
            focusin_flag = true;
        }
    }).focusout(function () {
        if (!focusout_flag ) {
            $(".search_prompt").hide();
            focusout_flag = true;
        } 
        function timeout_init() {
            setTimeout('search_prompt()', 2000);

        }

    });
});        
</script>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.search_intro {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #181469;
  background-image: url(../img/icons/info-icon.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 12px center;
  border: #CCC 1px solid;
  margin-top: 87px;
  margin-left:460px;
  position: absolute;
  width:198px;
  height:80px;
  background-color:#FFF;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px #CCC;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px #CCC;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px #030303;
  z-index:100;
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: May be the DOM not loaded and script is executed. You could use $(document).ready(function(){ /*do all your stuff here */}) ; More info http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 4):

it's probably flashing because external .css hasn't loaded yet. Try hiding it via inline css:

```
<div style="display: none">...</div>
```

so at last it's not visible while the rest of the css loads.

Comment: but if i do display none it doesnt load at all in jquery

Comment: You'll have make sure you remove/reset the `display` value when you want to show it again, using something like `$("#myNode").css({display:"block"});`

Comment: You can just do that in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var demoDiv = document.getElementById("demo-div");
  demoDiv.classList.remove("hidden");
  demoDiv.classList.add("not-hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.not-hidden {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  25% { opacity: 0.25; }
  50% { opacity: 0.5; }
  75% { opacity: 0.75; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">View Div</button>

<div class="hidden" id="demo-div">
  <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg">
  <p>Ut pharetra sollicitudin lobortis. Mauris viverra eros sed diam tristique ornare. Ut commodo iaculis velit non ullamcorper. Suspendisse ultricies, lectus finibus commodo ultricies, urna nibh porta justo, sit amet ultricies sapien sapien non dui.</p>
</div>
```